# After changing network properties, ubuntu doesn't finish booting

Tags: boot, networking

I changed my network `/etc/network/interfaces` settings to have a static IP but when I rebooted after that it didn't finish booting up.

It goes up to roundabout

```
*Starting AppArmor profiles                               [OK]
```

And then stops and doesn't continue. It also does:

```
*Configuring virtual network devices                      [fail]
```

I have access to the GRUB boot menu and from there I have access to the ROOT command shell.

In the `/etc/network/interfaces` is written:

```
#Interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auth eth0
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.135
dns nameserver 192.168.1.135 4.4.4.4
```

I thank everyone in advance

Comment: Post /etc/network/interfaces contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your interfaces file is malformed. Please amend it to:

```
#Interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.135
dns nameserver 192.168.1.135 4.4.4.4
```

Then get the system to re-read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Does it connect?

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: After having put in `ping -c3 www.google.com`  It gave me

    3 packets transmitted, 
    3 received, 0% packet loss

Comment: @chilli555 I have just booted up and I want to thank you a lot!!!! I am writing this from the computer that didn't want to boot up. What happened whas that I wrote: 
`iface eth0 intet static` in the interfaces file. Thanks once again.